# How to output based on the input conditions

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

1)If more than one instance with CategoryCd = GL AND selectedInd = 'Y' AND deletedInd = 'Y' on 2 different policies, then FAIL with return code FAILURE and return reason code MANYPOL

```
<policy VERSION_NO="1" MC_ID="66" ID="1">
    <businessGroupCdGvngOrgn>14</businessGroupCdGvngOrgn>
            <linesOfInsurance>
                <underlyingPolicy>
                    <PolicyNo>22</PolicyNo>
                    <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
                    <VersionNbr>2</VersionNbr>
                    <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
                    <CategoryCd>GL</CategoryCd>
                </underlyingPolicy>
                <underlyingPolicy ID="5">
                    <PolicyNo>22</PolicyNo>
                    <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
                    <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
                    <selectedInd>N</selectedInd>
                    <CategoryCd>GL</CategoryCd>
                </underlyingPolicy>     
                <underlyingPolicy ID="4">
                    <PolicyNo>11</PolicyNo>
                    <deletedInd>N</deletedInd>
                    <VersionNbr>2</VersionNbr>
                    <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
                    <CategoryCd>GL</CategoryCd>
                </underlyingPolicy>
                <underlyingPolicy ID="3">
                    <PolicyNo>11</PolicyNo>
                    <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
                    <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
                    <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
                    <CategoryCd>GL</CategoryCd>
                </underlyingPolicy>     
            </linesOfInsurance>
        </policy>
Expected O/P:
<AdaptikXML>
    <PWResponse>
        <ReturnCode>FAILURE</ReturnCode>
        <ReturnReasonCode>MANYPOL</ReturnReasonCode>
        <PWData>
            <policy VERSION_NO="1" MC_ID="66"/>
        </PWData>
    </PWResponse>
</AdaptikXML>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

2) If more than one instance with underlyingPolicyCategoryCd = GL AND selectedInd = 'Y' AND deletedInd = 'Y' on the same policy, then FAIL with return code FAILURE and return reason code MANY

```
<policy VERSION_NO="1" MC_ID="34">
    <businessGroupCd>14</businessGroupCd>
            <linesOfInsurance>
                <underlyingPolicy>
                    <PolicyNo>22</PolicyNo>
                    <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
                    <VersionNbr>2</VersionNbr>
                    <selectedInd>N</selectedInd>
                    <CategoryCd>GL</CategoryCd>
                </underlyingPolicy>
                <underlyingPolicy ID="5">
                    <PolicyNo>22</PolicyNo>
                    <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
                    <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
                    <selectedInd>N</selectedInd>
                    <CategoryCd>GL</CategoryCd>
                </underlyingPolicy>     
                <underlyingPolicy ID="4">
                    <PolicyNo>11</PolicyNo>
                    <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
                    <VersionNbr>2</VersionNbr>
                    <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
                    <CategoryCd>GL</CategoryCd>
                </underlyingPolicy>
                <underlyingPolicy ID="3">
                    <PolicyNo>11</PolicyNo>
                    <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
                    <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
                    <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
                    <CategoryCd>GL</CategoryCd>
                </underlyingPolicy>     
            </linesOfInsurance>
        </policy>
Expected O/P:
<AdaptikXML>
        <PWResponse>
            <ReturnCode>FAILURE</ReturnCode>
            <ReturnReasonCode>MANY</ReturnReasonCode>
            <PWData>
                <policy VERSION_NO="1" MC_ID="34"/>
            </PWData>
        </PWResponse>    
</AdaptikXML>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

3) If both the MANYPOL and MANY conditions are true, MANYPOL should be returned (this means that you can check for MANYPOL condition first and if that is true, you can stop processing and return

```
<policy VERSION_NO="1" MC_ID="66">
    <businessGroupCdGvngOrgn>14</businessGroupCdGvngOrgn>
            <linesOfInsurance>
                <underlyingPolicy>
                    <PolicyNo>22</PolicyNo>
                    <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
                    <VersionNbr>2</VersionNbr>
                    <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
                    <CategoryCd>GL</CategoryCd>
                </underlyingPolicy>
                <underlyingPolicy ID="5">
                    <PolicyNo>22</PolicyNo>
                    <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
                    <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
                    <selectedInd>N</selectedInd>
                    <CategoryCd>GL</CategoryCd>
                </underlyingPolicy>     
                <underlyingPolicy ID="4">
                    <PolicyNo>11</PolicyNo>
                    <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
                    <VersionNbr>2</VersionNbr>
                    <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
                    <CategoryCd>GL</CategoryCd>
                </underlyingPolicy>
                <underlyingPolicy ID="3">
                    <PolicyNo>11</PolicyNo>
                    <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
                    <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
                    <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
                    <CategoryCd>GL</CategoryCd>
                </underlyingPolicy>     
            </linesOfInsurance>
        </policy>
EXPECTED O/P:
    <AdaptikXML>
        <PWResponse>
            <ReturnCode>FAILURE</ReturnCode>
            <ReturnReasonCode>MANYPOL</ReturnReasonCode>
            <PWData>
                <policy VERSION_NO="1" MC_ID="66"/>
            </PWData>
        </PWResponse>
</AdaptikXML>
```

4)If there are no instances with underlyingPolicyCategoryCd = GL AND selectedInd = 'Y' AND deletedInd = 'Y' then Return code = SUCCESS and return reason code NOCHANGE

```
<policy VERSION_NO="1" MC_ID="56">
      <businessGroupCdGvngOrgn>14</businessGroupCdGvngOrgn>
        <linesOfInsurance>
            <underlyingPolicy ID="8">
                <PolicyNo>33</PolicyNo>
                <deletedInd>N</deletedInd>
                <VersionNbr>2</VersionNbr>
                <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
                <CategoryCd>AL</CategoryCd>
            </underlyingPolicy>
            <underlyingPolicy ID="7">
                <PolicyNo>33</PolicyNo>
                <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
                <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
                <selectedInd>N</selectedInd>
                <CategoryCd>AL</CategoryCd>
            </underlyingPolicy>         
            <underlyingPolicy>
                <PolicyNo>22</PolicyNo>
                <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
                <VersionNbr>2</VersionNbr>
                <selectedInd>N</selectedInd>
                <CategoryCd>GL</CategoryCd>
            </underlyingPolicy>
            <underlyingPolicy ID="5">
                <PolicyNo>22</PolicyNo>
                <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
                <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
                <selectedInd>N</selectedInd>
                <CategoryCd>GL</CategoryCd>
            </underlyingPolicy>     
            <underlyingPolicy ID="4">
                <PolicyNo>11</PolicyNo>
                <deletedInd>N</deletedInd>
                <VersionNbr>2</VersionNbr>
                <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
                <CategoryCd>GL</CategoryCd>
            </underlyingPolicy>
            <underlyingPolicy ID="3">
                <PolicyNo>11</PolicyNo>
                <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
                <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
                <selectedInd>N</selectedInd>
                <CategoryCd>GL</CategoryCd>
            </underlyingPolicy>     
        </linesOfInsurance>
    </policy>
Expected O/P:
<AdaptikXML>
    <PWResponse>
        <ReturnCode>SUCCESS</ReturnCode>
        <ReturnReasonCode>NOCHANGE</ReturnReasonCode>
        <ReturnMessage/>
        <PWData>
            <policy VERSION_NO="1" MC_ID="56"/>
        </PWData>
    </PWResponse>
</AdaptikXML>
```

---

Test case 3 - 2 GL policies with 2 quote versions each. Policy 22 version 1 has selectedInd = 'Y' AND deletedInd = 'Y' and policy 11 version 1 has selectedInd = 'Y' AND deletedInd = 'N'. The other 2 versions have selectedInd = 'N' AND deletedInd = 'Y'. End result should be Policy 22 version 1 has selectedInd = 'Y' AND deletedInd = 'N' and policy 11 version 1 has selectedInd = 'N' AND deletedInd = 'Y'.

```
<policy VERSION_NO="1" MC_ID="66">
    <businessGroupCdGvngOrgn>14</businessGroupCdGvngOrgn>
    <linesOfInsurance>            <underlyingPolicy>
            <PolicyNo>22</PolicyNo>
            <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
            <VersionNbr>2</VersionNbr>
            <selectedInd>N</selectedInd>
            <CategoryCd>GL</CategoryCd>
        </underlyingPolicy>
        <underlyingPolicy ID="5">
            <PolicyNo>22</PolicyNo>
            <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
            <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
            <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
            <CategoryCd>GL</CategoryCd>
        </underlyingPolicy>     
        <underlyingPolicy ID="4">
            <PolicyNo>11</PolicyNo>
            <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
            <VersionNbr>2</VersionNbr>
            <selectedInd>N</selectedInd>
            <CategoryCd>GL</CategoryCd>
        </underlyingPolicy>
        <underlyingPolicy ID="3">
            <PolicyNo>11</PolicyNo>
            <deletedInd>N</deletedInd>
            <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
            <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
            <CategoryCd>GL</CategoryCd>
        </underlyingPolicy>     
    </linesOfInsurance>
</policy>
```

Expected O/P:

```
<AdaptikXML>
    <PWResponse>
        <ReturnCode>SUCCESS</ReturnCode>
        <ReturnReasonCode>CHANGE</ReturnReasonCode>
        <ReturnMessage/>
        <PWData>
            <policy VERSION_NO="1" MC_ID="66" ExtAction="U">
                <linesOfInsurance ExtAction="U">
                    <underlyingPolicy ID="5" ExtAction="U">
                        <PolicyNo>22</PolicyNo>
                        <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
                        <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
                        <deletedInd>N</deletedInd>
                    </underlyingPolicy>
                    <underlyingPolicy ID="3" ExtAction="U">
                        <PolicyNo>11</PolicyNo>
                        <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
                        <selectedInd>N</selectedInd>
                        <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
                    </underlyingPolicy>
                </linesOfInsurance>
            </policy>
        </PWData>
    </PWResponse>
</AdaptikXML>
```

-___________________________________________________________________________________________

Test case 4 - 2 AL policies, 1 with 2 quote versions and 1 with 3. Policy 33 version 1 has selectedInd = 'Y' AND deletedInd = 'Y' and policy 44 version 2 has selectedInd = 'Y' AND deletedInd = 'Y'. End result should be Policy 33 version 1 and Policy 44 version 2 have selectedInd = 'Y' AND deletedInd = 'N'. Policy 33 version 2 and Policy 44 version 1 have selectedInd = 'N' AND deletedInd = 'Y'. Policy 44 version 3 stays unchanged (selectedInd = 'N' AND deletedInd = 'Y')

```
    <policy VERSION_NO="1" MC_ID="55">        
<businessGroupCdGvngOrgn>14</businessGroupCdGvngOrgn>
        <linesOfInsurance>            
<underlyingPolicy ID="7">
                <PolicyNo>44</PolicyNo>
                <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
                <VersionNbr>3</VersionNbr>
                <selectedInd>N</selectedInd>
                <CategoryCd>AL</CategoryCd>
            </underlyingPolicy>     
            <underlyingPolicy>
                <PolicyNo>44</PolicyNo>
                <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
                <VersionNbr>2</VersionNbr>
                <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
                <CategoryCd>AL</CategoryCd>
            </underlyingPolicy>
            <underlyingPolicy ID="5">
                <PolicyNo>44</PolicyNo>
                <deletedInd>N</deletedInd>
                <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
                <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
                <CategoryCd>AL</CategoryCd>
            </underlyingPolicy>     
            <underlyingPolicy ID="4">
                <PolicyNo>33</PolicyNo>
                <deletedInd>N</deletedInd>
                <VersionNbr>2</VersionNbr>
                <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
                <CategoryCd>AL</CategoryCd>
            </underlyingPolicy>
            <underlyingPolicy ID="3">
                <PolicyNo>33</PolicyNo>
                <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
                <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
                <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
                <CategoryCd>AL</CategoryCd>
            </underlyingPolicy>     
        </linesOfInsurance>
    </policy>
```

EXPECTED o/p:

```
<AdaptikXML>
    <PWResponse>
        <ReturnCode>SUCCESS</ReturnCode>
        <ReturnReasonCode>CHANGE</ReturnReasonCode>
        <ReturnMessage/>
        <PWData>
            <policy VERSION_NO="1" MC_ID="55" ExtAction="U">
                <linesOfInsurance ExtAction="U">
                    <underlyingPolicy ExtAction="U">
                        <PolicyNo>44</PolicyNo>
                        <VersionNbr>2</VersionNbr>
                        <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
                        <deletedInd>N</deletedInd>
                    </underlyingPolicy>
                    <underlyingPolicy ID="5" ExtAction="U">
                        <PolicyNo>44</PolicyNo>
                        <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
                        <selectedInd>N</selectedInd>
                        <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
                    </underlyingPolicy>
                    <underlyingPolicy ID="4" ExtAction="U">
                        <PolicyNo>33</PolicyNo>
                        <VersionNbr>2</VersionNbr>
                        <selectedInd>N</selectedInd>
                        <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
                    </underlyingPolicy>
                    <underlyingPolicy ID="3" ExtAction="U">
                        <PolicyNo>33</PolicyNo>
                        <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
                        <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
                        <deletedInd>N</deletedInd>
                    </underlyingPolicy>                 
                </linesOfInsurance>
            </policy>
        </PWData>
    </PWResponse>
</AdaptikXML>
```

---

Test case 5 - End result should be Policy 22 version 1 has selectedInd = 'Y' AND deletedInd = 'N' and policy 11 version 1 has selectedInd = 'N' AND deletedInd = 'Y'. Policy 33 version 1 and Policy 44 version 2 have selectedInd = 'Y' AND deletedInd = 'N'. Policy 33 version 2 and Policy 44 version 1 have selectedInd = 'N' AND deletedInd = 'Y'.

```
<policy VERSION_NO="1" MC_ID="89">
    <businessGroupCdGvngOrgn>14</businessGroupCdGvngOrgn>
    <linesOfInsurance>
        <underlyingPolicy ID="10">
            <PolicyNo>44</PolicyNo>
            <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
            <VersionNbr>2</VersionNbr>
            <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
            <CategoryCd>AL</CategoryCd>
        </underlyingPolicy>
        <underlyingPolicy ID="9">
            <PolicyNo>44</PolicyNo>
            <deletedInd>N</deletedInd>
            <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
            <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
            <CategoryCd>AL</CategoryCd>
        </underlyingPolicy>     
        <underlyingPolicy ID="8">
            <PolicyNo>33</PolicyNo>
            <deletedInd>N</deletedInd>
            <VersionNbr>2</VersionNbr>
            <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
            <CategoryCd>AL</CategoryCd>
        </underlyingPolicy>
        <underlyingPolicy ID="7">
            <PolicyNo>33</PolicyNo>
            <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
            <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
            <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
            <CategoryCd>AL</CategoryCd>
        </underlyingPolicy>
        <underlyingPolicy>
            <PolicyNo>22</PolicyNo>
            <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
            <VersionNbr>2</VersionNbr>
            <selectedInd>N</selectedInd>
            <CategoryCd>GL</CategoryCd>
        </underlyingPolicy>
        <underlyingPolicy ID="5">
            <PolicyNo>22</PolicyNo>
            <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
            <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
            <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
            <CategoryCd>GL</CategoryCd>
        </underlyingPolicy>     
        <underlyingPolicy ID="4">
            <PolicyNo>11</PolicyNo>
            <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
            <VersionNbr>2</VersionNbr>
            <selectedInd>N</selectedInd>
            <CategoryCd>GL</CategoryCd>
        </underlyingPolicy>
        <underlyingPolicy ID="3">
            <PolicyNo>11</PolicyNo>
            <deletedInd>N</deletedInd>
            <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
            <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
            <CategoryCd>GL</CategoryCd>
        </underlyingPolicy>                 
    </linesOfInsurance>
</policy>
```

expected O/P:

```
<AdaptikXML>
    <PWResponse>
        <ReturnCode>SUCCESS</ReturnCode>
        <ReturnReasonCode>CHANGE</ReturnReasonCode>
        <ReturnMessage/>
        <PWData>
            <policy VERSION_NO="1" MC_ID="89" ExtAction="U">
                <linesOfInsurance ExtAction="U">
                    <underlyingPolicy ID="5" ExtAction="U">
                        <PolicyNo>22</PolicyNo>
                        <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
                        <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
                        <deletedInd>N</deletedInd>
                    </underlyingPolicy>
                    <underlyingPolicy ID="3" ExtAction="U">
                        <PolicyNo>11</PolicyNo>
                        <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
                        <selectedInd>N</selectedInd>
                        <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
                    </underlyingPolicy>
                    <underlyingPolicy ID="10" ExtAction="U">
                        <PolicyNo>44</PolicyNo>
                        <VersionNbr>2</VersionNbr>
                        <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
                        <deletedInd>N</deletedInd>
                    </underlyingPolicy>
                    <underlyingPolicy ID="9" ExtAction="U">
                        <PolicyNo>44</PolicyNo>
                        <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
                        <selectedInd>N</selectedInd>
                        <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
                    </underlyingPolicy>
                    <underlyingPolicy ID="8" ExtAction="U">
                        <PolicyNo>33</PolicyNo>
                        <VersionNbr>2</VersionNbr>
                        <selectedInd>N</selectedInd>
                        <deletedInd>Y</deletedInd>
                    </underlyingPolicy>
                    <underlyingPolicy ID="7" ExtAction="U">
                        <PolicyNo>33</PolicyNo>
                        <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr>
                        <selectedInd>Y</selectedInd>
                        <deletedInd>N</deletedInd>
                    </underlyingPolicy>                                 
            </policy>
        </PWData>
    </PWResponse>
</AdaptikXML>
```

Comment: without getting into details, what is the output you are getting? which scenario doesn't work?

Comment: i m getting second scenario output but not 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stylesheet looks like it is doing more than just checking for "MANYPOL" and "MANY" but I will focus just on the task in hand...

Consider using a key to look up the `underlyingPolicy` elements by the relevant indicators

```
<xsl:key name="policy" 
         match="underlyingPolicy" 
         use="concat(CategoryCd, '|', selectedInd, '|', deletedInd)" />
```

Then, you can test if there are two different policy numbers with the same indicators like so:

```
<xsl:when test="linesOfInsurance/underlyingPolicy
                   [PolicyNo != key('policy', concat(CategoryCd, '|', selectedInd, '|', deletedInd))/PolicyNo]">
```

This gives you your `MANYPOL` result.

Now, you might be tempted to check for `MANY` just by doing changing the "not equals" to an "equals"

```
<xsl:when test="linesOfInsurance/underlyingPolicy
                   [PolicyNo = key('policy', concat(CategoryCd, '|', selectedInd, '|', deletedInd))/PolicyNo]">
```

This would not work though, as it would match the current `underlyingPolicy` element with itself! Instead, create a second key that includes the `PolicyNo`

```
<xsl:key name="policy_with_no" 
         match="underlyingPolicy" 
         use="concat(PolicyNo, '|', CategoryCd, '|', selectedInd, '|', deletedInd)" />
```

Then you can check if there are multiple policies of the same number which share the same indicators, like so:

```
 <xsl:when test="linesOfInsurance/underlyingPolicy
                    [key('policy_with_no', concat(PolicyNo, '|',CategoryCd, '|', selectedInd, '|', deletedInd))[2]]">
```

By using an `xsl:choose`, the first `xsl:when` is evaluated first, so MANYPOL will always be output, even when `MANY` is true too.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="policy" match="underlyingPolicy" use="concat(CategoryCd, '|', selectedInd, '|', deletedInd)" />
    <xsl:key name="policy_with_no" match="underlyingPolicy" use="concat(PolicyNo, '|', CategoryCd, '|', selectedInd, '|', deletedInd)" />

    <xsl:template match="/policy">
        <PWResponse>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="linesOfInsurance/underlyingPolicy[PolicyNo != key('policy', concat(CategoryCd, '|', selectedInd, '|', deletedInd))/PolicyNo]">
                    <ReturnCode>FAILURE</ReturnCode>
                    <ReturnReasonCode>MANYPOL</ReturnReasonCode>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="linesOfInsurance/underlyingPolicy[key('policy_with_no', concat(PolicyNo, '|',CategoryCd, '|', selectedInd, '|', deletedInd))[2]]">
                    <ReturnCode>FAILURE</ReturnCode>
                    <ReturnReasonCode>MANYPOL</ReturnReasonCode>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <ReturnCode>SUCCESS</ReturnCode>
                    <ReturnReasonCode></ReturnReasonCode>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </PWResponse>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim. i got the concept, there are 3 more cases which are quiet confusing to me.Can you please help in that too.i will added the input and expected output.

Comment: It may be better if you could put your question to back to how it was previously, and ask a whole new question with your new cases in. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Tim, will put put back the question with new test cases.

Comment: Hi  Tim,Please check I have added all the test cases.Thanks a lot for help

Comment: I meant put the new cases in a whole new question. The original question was answered and accepted, so it is confusing to add new cases to it at this stage. Thanks!

Comment: Ok Tim. Thanks will do that.